# think vs thought

Tags: grammaticality

Where is mistake or both sentences are correct?

> Did you enjoy the film? Yes, I think it was very good.
>
> Did you enjoy the film? Yes, I thought it was very good.

I like the first one, but what will you tell about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sentence is awkward temporally: "I [now] think it was very good [at the time that I saw it]" awkwardly combines two different timeframes. The second one consistently refers to one timeframe: "I thought it was very good [at the time that I saw it]."

To be less awkward the first one could be "Yes I think it is very good."

Comment: The first, however, is still correct. The second also carries the possibilty that you've changed your mind since seeing it - "I thought it was very good [at the time that I saw it but now I've had time to think it over I'm not so sure].